# Regular expression - skip characters in jMeter testing

Tags: regex, jmeter, nsregularexpression, extractor

I have the below regular expression which retrieves me all characters begins with

```
(state%3)((?:(?!#).)*)
```

I want to ignore the state%3. I have tried all kinds of lookback but nothing seems to work

Here is the full text that I need to match agains

"state%3DnGl%252BlPm8CkHfYd2PpBq7W0H2z6xgUeICgB7KFmGmGG8cTSQTf%252B9cYCfFSsT5YSPTITdbaLAlJoQ22%252FCXRAu3ROqTQYzpPfGYxKmRZ7iIqwx3g0GLpVkaXq5FL3Js5FcTGpncQx7TA9w1A6HsSyxxcktfwX8QSzhqJQj5lntOolrPoIqpa4l2C%252BbhCWuAOY18BwVynMv8%252BuSl#login/"

A couple of things I have already tried

```
^.{5}\Kstate
```

But seems not working. Any ideas. I need this to retrieve for jMeter testing.

Comment: Please check my answer below. If anything is unclear, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

No need of lookbehind, nor any lookarounds at all. Use a single capturing group and a negated character class:

```
state%3([^#]+)
```

**AND** set the template value to `$1$`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CwCll5/1). Details:

- `state%3` - matches a literal text
- `([^#]+)` - Capturing group #1 (that is why template should be `$1$`): one or more chars other than `#`.